# Serenity Jbehave use single browser for a set of stories?

Tags: java, automation, acceptance-testing, jbehave, serenity-bdd

Is there any way to use a single browser for all the jbehave stories written under a feature. Some what like using the property as below,

```
serenity.restart.browser.for.each = FEATURE
```

Tried to add this to my serenity.properties file. But was not working.
Is there anything I am doing wrong.

The serenity version used are as below

```
<serenity.version>1.5.0-rc.1</serenity.version>
<serenity.jbehave.version>1.26.0-rc.3</serenity.jbehave.version>
```

My Project Structure is under stories folder

```
   ---folder 1 [Capability]
          ---- folder 1.1 [Feature]
                  -----story 1 [.story]
                  -----story 2 [.story]
          ---- folder 1.2 [Feature]
                  -----story 3 [.story]
                  -----story 4 [.story]

   ---folder 2 [Capability]
          ---- folder 2.1 [Feature]
                  -----story 5 [.story]
                  -----story 6 [.story]
          ---- folder 2.2 [Feature]
                  -----story 7 [.story]
                  -----story 8 [.story]
```

I basically want to run the scenarios in story 1 and story 2 in a single browser and then open a new browser for story 3 and story 4. ie Story files in a single end folder should run in a single browser.

Is it possible to do so???

Answer (score 0):

You can try importing Spring libraries and create a singleton object for the driver your created. By this you can share the same browser session from anywhere. To have a new browser for the second instance, quit the browser session in the singleton object and redefine it.

Comment: Could you please give me a elaborate answer. I am totally new to automation and clue less about how to make it work. It will be really helpful if you can help with me with some steps. I am using eclipse for the coding.